# Undefined results on calling module.exports in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

my app.js contents:

```
 var greet3=require('./greet3');
 greet3.greet();
```

my greet3.js contents

```
  function Greetr(){
  this.greeting='greet3';
  this.greet=function(){
    console.log(this.greeting);
   }
  }
   module.exports=new Greetr();
```

my console window output :  greet3

but when i change the contents of app.js as :

```
 var greet3=require('./greet3');
 greet3();
```

i get the ouput as 'undefined'

I am a beginner in node.js and was trying different module patterns in it.I need help on why I am getting the result as undefined

Comment: When I do that, I get `greet3 is not a function`, as expected. You are exporting an Object, but trying to call it as if it's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your above module, the line

```
var greet3=require('./greet3');
```

essentially becomes:

```
var greet3 = {
  greeting: "greet3",
  greet: function(){
    console.log(this.greeting);
  }
}
```

So in app.js, `greet3` is now an Object. `greet3.greet();` works as expected and logs `"greet3"`.

But `greet3()` produces `greet3 is not a function`, since `greet3` isn't a function.

Comment: Your explanation helped me.Please help me figure this out as well- when I change the require in app.js to "require('./greet3').greet ;" and try to access the greeting property why does it gives me the result as 'undefined'.Thanks for your help

Comment: @Raman because now you've said `var greet3 = function() { console.log(this.greeting) };` and thus `this.greeting` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting a initialised object, when you set var greet3=require('./greet3') and call greet3() you are trying to use the object as a function, hence it says undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in `greet3.js`:

```
  module.exports = function(){
  this.greeting='greet3';
  this.greet=function(){
    console.log(this.greeting);
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said before, your code is working as expected.
Your module:

```
function Greetr(){
  this.greeting='greet3';
  this.greet=function(){
    console.log(this.greeting);
  }
}
module.exports=new Greetr();
```

Returns an object, but I think you wanted to return a function, so the last line should look like this:

```
module.exports=Greetr;
```

Instead of this:

```
module.exports=new Greetr();
```

Because now when you call:

```
var greet3=require('./greet3');
greet3();
```

It assigns object of function Greetr to a variable greet3 and you cannot call an object.